# Maven: How to deal with modules that contain modules?

Tags: java, xml, maven, pom.xml, parent-pom

Previously I have worked with multi-module Maven projects that consisted out of two hierarchies. The parent POM followed by modules in their own directories and POMs.

But now I have taken over a project that contains a parent, followed by modules which again contain modules.

**Is this all according to Maven guidelines or am I dealing with something customized?**

**And how to I interpret these sub-modules? Know a guide you can point me to?**

I can run all Maven lifecycles successfully. Though I'm unsure whether and how to refactor the application and start inserting my own code.

Here is a tree of my project structure with only a few modules left:

```
top-parent
|   pom.xml (modules: applications, checks, core, test)
|           
+---applications 
|   |   pom.xml (parent: top-parent) (modules: batch, surefire, web)    
|       <parent>
|         <artifactId>applications</artifactId>
|         <groupId>com.a.b.codechecker</groupId>
|         <version>1.0</version>
|       </parent>
|       <artifactId>batch</artifactId>  
|  
|   |                       
|   \---web
|       |   pom.xml
|           <parent>
|             <groupId>com.a.b.codechecker</groupId>
|             <artifactId>applications</artifactId>             
|             <version>1.0</version>
|           </parent>
|           <artifactId>web</artifactId>
|                               
+---checks
|   |   pom.xml (parent: top parent) (modules: aggregator, blacklist-check)
|       <parent>
|         <groupId>com.a.b.codechecker</groupId>
|         <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
|         <version>1.0</version>
|       </parent>
|       <groupId>com.a.b.codechecker.checks</groupId>
|       <artifactId>checks</artifactId>
|   |
|   +---aggregator
|       |   pom.xml
            <parent>
              <artifactId>checks</artifactId>
              <groupId>com.a.b.codechecker.checks</groupId>
              <version>1.0</version>
            </parent>
            <artifactId>aggregator</artifactId>
```

Comment: The structure looks fine and the childs of childs have the correct parent like blacklist-check has parent checks ..correct ..There is practical no limitation of the number of levels...But I . would questioning some of the names of the modules like `test` ?

Comment: That module "provides helper classes to simplify automated tested and test data generation" (from the Readme). But it's good to hear that it's generally fine to have several levels. Is there a difference between `<groupId>com.a.b.codechecker.checks</groupId>` in the aggregator and no explicit `groupId` in the `applications`?

Comment: Can you clarify this line "how to I interpret these sub-modules"  so that we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I provide below few outlines.

As per the question,
**Is this all according to Maven guidelines or am I dealing with something customized?**

Yes, you can have Parent, Child, Grand child type module structure.Parent and Child type maven multi module hierarchy is simple, but in some cases, developers design to have several sub modules inside a module. If you have large project having n number of modules and m number of submodules, it becomes complex for different levels of developers.

As per this question,
**And how to I interpret these sub-modules? Know a guide you can point me to?**
It is upto the development team about how to manage for simplicity. I would recommend, if you have many sub modules, you can create/maintain another independent project and you can add the dependency to the main project wherever it is required. It will provide you the granularity and a separate team work on this project without considering the main project.

In case of large project, it is always recommended to maintain independent projects and you can add the dependency in other projects. For this you can use Nexus or Artifactory for artifact management.

Comment: This answered my question well. I'm a trainee/student and was irritated by such structure. In addition the effective POMs looked weird because many dependencies very doubled but with a different `groupId`,  probably due to the inconsistent use of `project.parent.groupid` and 'project.groupid'. Since it is a very small project (for your scale I guess) I decided to flatten out the structure and refactor the POMs. There will never be more than one person working on this project anyway.

Comment: Yes @JellyFilledNuts